# asp.net mvc remote validation with jquery

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-validate, jquery-chosen

I need a help.
I have a User registration form and I have to map "Customer" with user.

Now I want to validate user "customer" which is came from another source and I put the "customer" in Select list "customer" are more then 2000 that's why I use JQuery Chosen plugin to search in select list
but "customer" Field depend on "roles" that's why on page load "customer" field is hidden by default when I change the role "customer" field(chosen select list) display and when i am Selecting customer its not firing remote validation.
I tried to make it visible on "inspect element" and I change the display:none to display:bock and try to change value from chosen its not working when i change the orignal select list value from clicking on select list  then its working fine i mean its firing my remote validator method here is full code example what i am doing. 
please help i want to validate on when chosen select list value change.

**This is RegisterViewModel**

```cs
    public class RegisterViewModel
    {
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Role")]
        public string Role { get; set; }

        //for edit view model additionalFields which will only require for edit mode
        //[System.Web.Mvc.Remote("DoesCustomerCodeExist", "Account", AdditionalFields = "OldCustomerCode")]
        [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "Customer Code is required.")]
        [Display(Name = "Customer Code", Description = "A customer code come from our oracle system.")]
        [System.Web.Mvc.Remote("DoesCustomerCodeExist", "Account")]
        [Range(0, int.MaxValue, ErrorMessage = "Please enter valid Customer Code in number only.")]
        public string CustomerCode { get; set; }

    }
```

**Here is my view cshtml** in this file also have js code to display customers chosen Select list when role changed.

```cshtml
//select Role
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Role, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Role, ViewBag.Roles as SelectList,"", new { @class = "form-control chosen-select", data_placeholder = "Select a Role" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Role, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>

//Customer Code
<div class="form-group condition-div user hidden ">
    //this hidden field is only for edit mode
    //@Html.Hidden("OldCustomerCode", Model.CustomerCode)
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.CustomerCode, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.CustomerCode, (SelectList)ViewBag.Customers, "", new { @class = "form-control  chosen-customers", data_placeholder = "Select Customer" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.CustomerCode, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>


@section    Styles{
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/chosen")
}

@section Scripts {
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/chosen")

<script type="text/javascript">
        $('input[type=text]').tooltip(
                 {
                     placement: "right",
                     trigger: "focus"
                 }
            );

        $(".chosen-select").chosen({ allow_single_deselect: true});

        $('#Role').change(function () {

            if (this.value == "") {
                $('.condition-div').addClass('hidden'); // hide all the conidional divs
            } else if (this.value == "NBP User" || this.value == "NBP Head" ) {
                $('.condition-div.admin').addClass('hidden'); /// hide admin conditional divs
                $('.condition-div.user').removeClass('hidden'); // show user role conditioanl div
                //configure selectlist to Chosen select and if i remove this line and show orignal select list its working fine mean remote validating on change  but if i use this is not working on change.
                $(".chosen-customers").chosen({ allow_single_deselect: true, search_contains: true }); 
                $.validator.setDefaults({ ignore: ":hidden:not(.chosen-customers)" });
            } else if (this.value == "ICIL User" || this.value == "ICIL Head" || this.value == "FIO User" ) {
                $('.condition-div.user').addClass('hidden'); /// hide user role conditional divs
                $('.condition-div.admin').removeClass('hidden'); // show admin role conditional divs
                $(".chosen-branch").chosen({ allow_single_deselect: true });
                $.validator.setDefaults();
            }
        });
</script>
}
```

**Controller Action** to validate Customer Code

```cs
    public ActionResult DoesCustomerCodeExist(string CustomerCode, string OldCustomerCode)
    {
        //the oldCustomerCode will come null in this case cause its register view and in edit view OldCustomerCode will be use
        if (CustomerCode == OldCustomerCode)
            return Json(true, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

        if (DbContext.Users.Any(x => x.CustomerCode == CustomerCode))
            return Json("Customer code already exists in application. Please verify user details.", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

        if (DbOracle.IsCustomerCodeExist(CustomerCode))
            return Json(true, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        else
            return Json("The customer code does not exist in database.", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

All code working fine if i did not use jquery chosen plugin.
In short issue is when I use chosen plugin for select list remote validation is stop validating values.
I can share images if u guys need now I have a limited account so i cant upload snaps shots....
Please help me.

Comment: I use OldCustomerCode in my edit view and worked fine without chosen when i use chosen it's gonna stop validating

Comment: @StephenMuecke why you marked as duplicate?

Comment: yes i read all those answers and i implement that in other application and those are working fine but those validation are for requried or match type no remote validation and u can read that line $.validator.setDefaults({ ignore: ":hidden:not(.chosen-customers)" }); its mean  ignore all except with the class of ".chosen-customers". and i use it when role change.

Comment: Please remove duplicate mark. cause i read many question but i didn't found any answer helpful in this case

Comment: but why u would'nt remove duplicate check if this is duplicate then refer the question. and i try what u suggest to me i am gonna put this line to top of the script tag but its conditional if i didn't select that type of role then i don't wanna validate it.

Comment: Its not duplicate which question u refer there is only removing ignore case in jquery validator and i did it befor don't do that with me please up vote and remove duplicate  if u understand what i am asking for. thanx

Comment: let me try and i'll update but its not duplicate u should assume that. thank for your time.

Comment: please u can read my last line where i am clearly saying that .In short issue is when I use chosen plugin for select list **remote** validation is stop validating values

Comment: now i remove all conditions and add `$.validator.setDefaults({ ignore: ":hidden:not(.chosen-customers)" });` as the first line of code in <scripts> and test it its still not working and on client side required type of validation working but not remote validation  and i did one more thing which is inspect element and show original select list and change the value from it and its fire the server event my English is not so good. so sorry for inconvenient.

Comment: @StephenMuecke Please remove it from duplicate i also mention in title remote validation and its about when i use chosen remote validation is stop working. The solution which u provide i also visit before i ask question and i implement it before in other application works fine but this is about remote validation is stop and even i add ignore condition in jquery validator. please remove it from duplicate.

Comment: @StephenMuecke I got solution please reopen it then I answer to  my own question

Comment: @StephenMuecke Thanks for reopen  its just about to call focusout Event of that selectlist on change. `$('#CustomerCode').change(function () {
            $(this).focusout();
        });`

Comment: query validate uses the `blur()` event, not `focusout()` and all your doing is writing one more bad hack to fix the bad code in the first place

Comment: @StephenMuecke Thanks you can help me yesterday now i am using blur(). The issue is only is not firing the event chosen just change the value of Original select list and i just call the event the how is this bad hack rather then write whole custom code for remote validation or just a line to fire the event. by the way thanks for reopen it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should have to put some JQuery on client side to track the "CustomerCode" field when change of customer field jsut call "focusout()" event of "CustomerCode" e.g:

```cshtml
    $('#CustomerCode').change(function () {
        $(this).focusout();
    });
```